# agregar tag a posts wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Saludos a todos

Tengo este código que usaba hace tiempo, ahora quiero usarlo en un proyecto nuevo con Wordpress y no funciona.

Este código agrega a los posts un tag con la ciudad correspondiente, justo después de ser publicados. Pero ya no lo realiza. Ciudad es un campo extendido en el perfil del usuario con Buddypress, el campo es el correcto, si imprimo la variable si muestra la ciudad.

Espero puedan orientarme en que estoy errado. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
/*********** agrega ciudad y tipo de noticia a los posts ***********/
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'update_post_terms' );
function update_post_terms( $post_id ) 
{
    $cu = wp_get_current_user(); //usuario actual
    $valorC=xprofile_get_field_data('Ciudad',$cu->ID); //ciudad tag
    $valorI=xprofile_get_field_data('intereses',$cu->ID); //categoria
    $categoria="";
    foreach($valorI as $posicion=>$interes) 
    {
        switch ($interes) 
        {
        case "Noticias":
            $categoria="Noticias";
            break;
        case "Deportes":
            $categoria="Deportes";
            break;
        case "Eventos":
            $categoria="Eventos";
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $parent = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        $post_id = $parent;
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
        return;
    // add a tag
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $valorC, 'post_tag', true );
    // add a category
$valorI='Intereses';
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
    $newcat = get_term_by( 'name', $valorI, 'category' );
    array_push( $categories, $newcat->term_id );
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $categories );
}
```

Espero puedan orientarme.

Comment: Pero ¿la función se lanza cuando creas un post? ¿Depuraste las otras variables? ¿Verificaste que el código sigue el flujo correcto?

Comment: la función se lanzaba justo después de crear un post, respecto a las otras variables SI son las correctas. comento eso funcionaba al 100, pero ahora lo uso en un tema nuevo uso customizr con un tema child